# Apply wrapper at import (python)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to have a complete module "vectorized"?

What I have:

- python module with many functions accepting float/returning float
- `__all__` is properly defined in that module

What I want to do:

- have `numpy` float vectors
- `from my_module import *` to import directly into the namespace
- call `return eval('function_from_my_module(my_numpy_vector, ...)`

The problem is of course now, that I had to apply `numpy.vectorize` (which works beautifully for my use case) on all of the functions coming from the module with the functions.

What is the best way to have the functions "vectorized" on import automagically (remember, `__all__` is defined already)?

Comment: Why is applying `vectorize` a problem in the first place?

Comment: Of course applying ``numpy.vectorize`` is no problem by just writing it down. However, my point is having some lines of code which will apply ``numpy.vectorize`` automatically on all elements in ``__all__``, which could be a rather long list.

Comment: You may do so using `dir` on the module, extract from there the callable functions, and then reassign their symbols, possibly using `eval`. This looks like a hack, and I can't see a good reason to not simply apply a `vectorize` decorator to the functions.

Comment: It is not necessary to extract something from ``dir(...)`` because all function names to import are already specified in ``__all__``. So I could iterater over it and use ``__import__``, but I am not sure how. Plan B will be just to write ``func = numpy.vectorize(func)``. The decorator is no option, because I do not want to modify the underlying library (which is basically a wrapper using ctypes).